How do hardware patents affect apps/software?
A smartphone app I'm working on uses vibrations to notify the user to do a certain action.
A few years ago (before the app was released), some company filed a patent for a device that does exactly the same.
Question now is, do I need to remove the vibration feature from the app, or is it safe to keep it in?
AFAIK, software patents aren't accepted in Europe. Does this by implication protect smartphone apps (which are software solutions) from license claims?
How do apps usually deal with these kind of situations?
Any clarifications are greatly appreciated.

As pointed out in a comment, read the patent claims carefully. Almost all patents have multiple claims, numbered starting at 1. Independent claims stand alone and dependent claims include the limitations of other claims by reference.
If you make, sell, offer for sale, import or use a product that falls under any single claim, in the territory covered by patent, you would be infringing.
In SE’s Ask Patents we get may people pointing to some patent documents with concern and the document turns out not to be a granted patent at all but a published application with no force at all so start being sure it is actually an issued patent.
Then read each claim carefully. To infringe you must do all steps required by at least one claim. Reading claims and understanding how a judge and jury might interpret them is an art unto itself.
It may be that the patent you are initially concerned with doesn’t cover your product but another patent by the same or different inventors does cover your product.
Only patents issued by places that include your activities are relevant. A US patent is meaningless in Canada.
Software can be patented in the EPO. They say a program per se can’t be patented but if it has a “technical effect” it can. So no to a sort algorithm but maybe yes to a vibrating notice.

and then there are software-hardware interactions that can be patentable, such as those that result in a 3D printer.

Usually a machine together with the patented software is protected by patent law, if the machine without the software is not capable of infringement, and nor is the software as long as it is not on the machine.
Microsoft was involved in a patent case about a nine digit sum years ago, and an essential question was whether an infringing machine was built in the USA or not. The decision was that the infringing machine was created when an end user installed a DVD with the software on the computer. Not when the computer was built, not when Microsoft pressed millions of DVDs with the software, but when the software was installed.

It depends on how the claim is worded. A method claim is infringed by whoever sets the method in action. A system claim can be infringed by a machine that is turned off and on a shelf if the relevant software is installed. A non-transient storage medium claim is infringed by making, selling, offering for sale or importing the media (CD,  DVD, etc) as well as using the media.
